# how to use images uploaded to public://

Tags: 7, media, uri

with a form I've got the possibility to upload images, this is the piece of code that says where the files go: `'#upload_location' => 'public://',`

this is the piece of code which generates the rows in my table view:

```
$rows[] = array(
        'data' => array(
            l($node->id, 'node/'. $node->id),
            $node->url,
            $node->title,
            $icon = "<img src='$node->icon'>",
            $node->created,
            $delete = "<a id='delete' href='$node->id/delete'> " . t('Delete') . "</a> | <a id='edit' href='$node->id/edit'> " . t('Edit') . "</a>"
        )
  );
```

notice '$icon'. $node->icon returns for example usa.gif. But of course the path is invalid.

The question is: how can I use my images? I cant figure it out

There's probably some drupal way to do this, advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: You can also try file_create_url($uri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$node->icon` is the path relative to public://, then you can use the following code.

```
if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri("public://{$node->icon}")) {
  $url = $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
}
```

The code works also for stream wrappers that are not local, for which the file is not local to the server running the code.